# libsodium - Using the key exchange API to generate shared keys

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

The documentation for the key exchange API ([here](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/key_exchange)) is a little thin, so for all I know I'm misunderstanding how this is supposed to work. How I expect it to work, and how I've implemented it is:

1. Generate a keypair on both clients using `crypto_kx_keypair()`.
2. Generate (using `crypto_kx_keypair()`) and return a public key from a server and send that to both the above clients.
3. On both clients, use `crypto_kx_client_session_keys(client_pk, client_sk, server_pk)` along with their respective keypairs generated in step 1, to computed a shared key.

I would suspect the shared key generated on both clients to be the same. But using the above method it is not.

I've tried using one of the client's public keys in place of the public server key, but that didn't work either. Also tried swapping the clients' public keys and using those instead for each other client, but that still had the same problem.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It think it's correct that they're not the same. If you encode something on one end and can you decode on the other side?

Comment: I've tried, as the documentation said, to use the "tx" value from client A to encode the message and then the "rx" value on client B to decode it. But that resulted in an error about the incorrect keys for the provided ciphertext. Part of the issue here is that the documentation doesn't make it entirely clear which keys are supposed to be used when generating the shared keys, so I'm not entirely sure if I'm generating it properly.

Comment: That was also asked, and responded here: https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/issues/855